# Checking Maven Variables to avoid parallel versioning problems

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

In our company we have two parallel projects with similar versioning. Let's call one *fw* and the other one *app*. Version numbers are based on the release month, f.e. 19.5, 19.6 etc. These can be appended by incremented numbers, so *fw* could use 19.5.0-15, whereas *app* is at 19.5.0-125. So technically any *fw*-version *could* be a correct version in *app* and vice versa.

*app* consists of a bigger amount of sub-projects. The parent pom defines the *app* version, which is applied to all sub-projects. It also defines a variable fw.version, which points to the currently used version of *fw*. It is available in the sub-projects, too.

In general, developers in *app* use the variable project.version to declare dependencies between sub-projects.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>app</groupId>
   <artifactId>app.subproject</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course they can also declare dependencies to a part of *fw*

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>fw</groupId>
   <artifactId>fw.subproject</artifactId>
   <version>${fw.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But sometimes, due to copy-and-paste, they use a *fw* version for a *app* dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>app</groupId>
   <artifactId>app.subproject</artifactId>
   <version>${fw.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This might work well for a while, if app.subproject is available in the repository. But eventually it will be unavailable, so the build crashes.

Is there a way, maybe by maven-plugin, to detect and avoid this kind of problem? Reviewing the Pull-Request did not prove sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but there is an enforcer rule

https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/reactorModuleConvergence.html

This rule checks different "good practises" for a multi-module build, including the requirement that dependencies to other modules have the correct version.

I would give it a try.